# How to install and run nautilus using macports (or any other way)

Tags: macos, finder, macports

I've installed macports and then done 'sudo port install nautilus' to install nautilus, which all works fine. Now i'm not sure how to actually run nautilus - there's no app in the applications, and if i do 'nautilus' from the terminal it simply throws up a lot of errors.

Am i missing something?

Thanks

And the errors are below:

```
:~ $ nautilus

Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!

(nautilus:41295): Eel-WARNING **: GConf error:
  Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Not enough memory)
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!

(nautilus:41295): Eel-WARNING **: GConf error:
  Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Not enough memory)
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!

(nautilus:41295): Eel-WARNING **: GConf error:
  Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Not enough memory)
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!

(nautilus:41295): Eel-WARNING **: GConf error:
  Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Not enough memory)
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
GConf warning: failure listing pairs in `/apps/nautilus/preferences': Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Not enough memory)Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
GConf warning: failure listing pairs in `/desktop/gnome/file_views': Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Not enough memory)Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
GConf warning: failure listing pairs in `/desktop/gnome/background': Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Not enough memory)Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
GConf warning: failure listing pairs in `/desktop/gnome/lockdown': Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Not enough memory)Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
GConf warning: failure listing pairs in `/apps/nautilus/desktop': Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Not enough memory)Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
GConf warning: failure listing pairs in `/apps/nautilus/icon_view': Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Not enough memory)Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
GConf warning: failure listing pairs in `/apps/nautilus/desktop-metadata': Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Not enough memory)Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!

(nautilus:41295): Unique-DBus-WARNING **: Unable to open a connection to the session bus: Not enough memory

(nautilus:41295): Unique-DBus-WARNING **: Unable to connect to the running instance, aborting.
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!

(nautilus:41295): Unique-DBus-WARNING **: Unable to open a connection to the session bus: Not enough memory

(nautilus:41295): Unique-DBus-WARNING **: Unable to connect to the running instance, aborting.
```

Comment: Is X11 running?

Comment: It starts XQuartz automatically when i run the 'nautilus' command, is that the same thing?

Comment: yes that is roughly the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

This problem sounds like you did not set up dbus yet. Read the output of the command `port notes dbus` and follow the instructions.

```
$ port notes dbus
dbus has the following notes:
  ############################################################################
  # Startup items have been generated that will aid in
  # starting dbus with launchd. They are disabled
  # by default. Execute the following command to start them,
  # and to cause them to launch at startup:
  #
  # sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.freedesktop.dbus-system.plist
  # launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist
  ############################################################################
```