# Help getting Nautilus running under MacPorts

Tags: snow-leopard, macports, x11

I have been trying to run Nautilus on OS X 10.6.8 without any luck. First, I installed MacPorts, then installed Nautilus. However when I try to run it from the command line, I am getting an error. I came to [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8032/how-to-install-and-run-nautilus-using-macports-or-any-other-way) and followed the instructions given. However I am still getting this error:

```
(nautilus:27170): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display "/tmp/launch-42nv45/org.x:0".

** (nautilus:27170): WARNING **: Can not calculate _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS

** (nautilus:27170): WARNING **: Can not calculate _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS

** (nautilus:27170): WARNING **: Can not get _NET_WORKAREA

** (nautilus:27170): WARNING **: Can not determine workarea, guessing at layout
nautilus: Fatal IO error 0 (Unknown error: 0) on X server /tmp/launch-42nv45/org.x:0.
```

And then X11 stops unexpectedly. Can anybody tell me how to solve this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is needs more information e.g. output from consoles

Comment: Chances of finding more information is slim after 2 years !!

Answer (score 3):

You need to install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.org/) instead, which is a package providing an X11 server for Mac OS X.